# How far in advance should I post a reminder for a scheduled livestream to maximize viewership?

Tags: user-engagement, communication, promotion

I help run the social media for (and am a player in) a weekly *Dungeons & Dragons* 5th edition actual-play podcast called *Planeslip: Echoes of Creation*. The campaign is set in a homebrew setting of the Dungeon Master's own creation. We normally livestream episodes every Wednesday night at midnight EST.

I usually post a reminder about the stream on the show's Facebook and Twitter, as well as on a number of other relevant communities that I'm a part of (e.g. the [Role-Playing Games Stack Exchange General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), and a number of Discord servers I'm in).

full version of this reminder includes a link and a reminder of when the stream starts (along with the podcast name and that it's a D&D 5e podcast), a 3-4 sentence synopsis of the premise of the campaign, a 1-3 sentence synopsis of the current arc, and 1-2 sentences teasing the current episode, and concludes with a reminder of the starting time. The short version of this reminder (for Twitter) just includes the starting time, the link, and the 1-2 sentence teaser for the current episode.

I usually post these reminders between 15 and 45 minutes before the stream, though I haven't really stuck to a specific time - it mostly just depends on when the DM gives me the 1-2 sentence teaser (as a player, I don't necessarily know what the session has in store for us otherwise).

**Are there any best practices in terms of how far in advance a livestreamed show (on a set schedule) should be advertised in order to maximize viewership?**

- Do these best practices vary based on the type of livestream (e.g.
  livestreams of a video game vs. a tabletop RPG vs. some other sort of
  livestream)?
- Does the ideal advance time to post vary based on the platform the
  reminder is being shared on (e.g. Facebook vs. Twitter vs. Discord)?

Please support answers by citing evidence or experience, per [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

---

[This question asks about when to post content to maximize engagement](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/what-time-should-i-post-content-as-to-maximise-engagement), but it seems to be about Facebook posts rather than livestreams.

Comment: You could try to find that out by yourself. Vary the times randomly and then correlate them with the viewership numbers. There might be an optimum somewhere. From commercial companies that send me advertisement mails I usually get a reminder of a webinar a few days in advance and directly on the day of the event in the morning. For other type of events and other audiences, it might differ.